# Relationship between switching pattern and the harmonics generated

Tags: converter, switching, harmonics

Is there any relationship between the switching pattern of a power converter and the harmonics generated (amplitude & phase) ?

i want to predict the generated harmonics based on the switching pattern.

NB : i need also any kind of documentation about that topic

Comment: Harmonics will occur at integer multiples of the fundamental switching frequency. Also if you have a non 50% duty cycle you will get some odd frequency that result due to the effective frequency required to produce the odd duty cycle.

Comment: what about Harmonics's phase ? and Amplitude ? is there anyway ?

Comment: If you are talking about things like 3-phase variable speed drives, you may find it useful to search for terms like '6-pulse 12-pulse harmonics'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The switching pattern is the essential factor that determines the amplitude and phase of the harmonic components. The switching pattern determines the waveform of the current and/or voltage produced. The fourier analysis of the waveform provides the amplitudes and phase of the harmonic components. Usually only the amplitude is of interest, so the fourier analysis is simplified to give only the amplitude, but both the amplitude and phase can be obtained. You should be able to find extensive information on fourier analysis. Here is a link a PDF textbook chapter that seems to have the relevant information: [LINK](https://engineering.purdue.edu/ME365/Textbook/chapter8.pdf)

Note that switching pattern is not the only factor. In many situations, the switching pattern determines the voltage waveform, but the voltage waveform must be applied to a complex loop impedance to determine the current waveform.

Comment: what you said was very helpful, specially the last part ! "Note that switching pattern is not the only factor", what are the other factors ! i mean the controllable factors (all i can think about are pattern switching and specially : Freqancy and D%) am i right ?

Comment: To be exact is it possible to find a relationship between those factors and the Phase & Amplitude of certain Harmonic rank ! (3rd for example) !! this is very importe to me

Comment: The complex value of the relevant loop impedance is the primary "other factor." The switching pattern determines the theoretical voltage and current waveforms. When you are dealing with harmonics, the rise time characteristics of the switches and other factors like that may be important. You may need to use a good simulation of the entire system to get the true waveform. Then you do a fourier analysis on the true waveform.

Comment: so is it possible to predict the harmonics amplitude but specially **phase of those harmonics** (at least few one 3rd, 5th and 7th for example) based on the switching pattern !?
is it possible or is it a dead end ?!

Comment: If you can get a waveform to analyze, the proper fourier analysis will give you the complete harmonic spectrum including both the amplitude and phase of each harmonic with respect to the fundamental.

Comment: i thought about something i wanted your opinion on it, i thought about making a design experiments where i use a simple switching circuit, and i vary parameters of the switching control, and observe the harmonics (phase and amplitude), and try to run some AI algorithm on the data, may be it can give me some sort of transfer function that will give me the relationship between the switching parameters and the harmonics generated without having to model the system in an analytic way ? what do you think ?

Comment: I don't know anything about AI or what sort of problems it can be applied to. The harmonic spectrum of the current drawn by a switching circuit at the input terminals will be determined by the switching parameters and the impedance of the circuit, its load and the source. I have seen product full-load harmonic current spectrums characteristics by plotting the amplitude of the most significant harmonics vs. source impedance or short circuit ratio. If you want to discuss this in detail, we should figure out what forum would be appropriate.

Comment: look, i know what i am about to ask you is against the forum rules, but it is very important to me, i looked up for your name on facebook, can i get in touch with you there ? or if you want you can give me your mail address ? i will perfectly understand if you can't, you've being with a big help to me sir.

Comment: Facebook is good. I will watch for your message.